ValueError: The layer sequential has never been called and thus has no defined input. Tensorflow/pydot collision
I am trying to implement a custom net with a normal dense layer and an RBF layer following tutorial:text. The dense layer act as an ENCODER, whil RBF clusters the encoded input. I accually solved that, and the model wos working perfeclty.
Here the code of the custom RBF layer:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
class RBFLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, gamma, **kwargs):
        super(RBFLayer , self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.gamma = K.cast_to_floatx(gamma)
    def build(self, input_shape):
#         print(input_shape)
#         print(self.units)
        self.mu = self.add_weight(name='mu',
                                  shape=(int(input_shape[1]), self.units),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
        super(RBFLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        diff = K.expand_dims(inputs) - self.mu
        l2 = K.sum(K.pow(diff, 2), axis=1)
        res = K.exp(-1 * self.gamma * l2)
        return res

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.units)```

here the code of the keras implementation:

from modules_files.Feature_Selection_module import \*
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback, EarlyStopping
from RBFLayer import RBFLayer
import os
def get_neural_network_model2(\*\*kwargs):
X_train = kwargs\['X_train'\]
y_train = kwargs\['y_train'\]
epochs = kwargs\['epochs'\]
verbose = kwargs\['verbose'\]
SEED = kwargs\['SEED'\]
\# epochs  = 30
input_size = X_train.shape\[1\]
output_size = y_train.shape\[1\]

    keras.utils.set_random_seed(SEED)
    tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(input_size,
                    activation='relu',
                    kernel_regularizer = regularizers.L1L2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
                    bias_regularizer = regularizers.L2(1e-4),
                    activity_regularizer = regularizers.L2(1e-5))
    )
    model.add(RBFLayer(output_size, 0.5))
    print(" Compile the model")
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(" Train the model")
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose, batch_size=1000)
    
    return model

Next I was curiuos about plotting the model (in order to chek correctness) using the following line tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, "model.png", show_shapes=True) and Pycharm told me to update/install pydot. So I did it using automatic pycharm features, and I have udated also tensorflow and keras for that. Now nothing is working any more.
After fixing some virtual enviroment pakeges settings, I was able to restore the training process BY downgrading tensorflow to 2.16.1 version(I actually don't remember what tensor flow version I had before when the code was working).
So I can train the model with good accuracy but if i try to isolate the encoder part whit the following command :
encoded_model = Model(inputs=NN_model.input, outputs=NN_model.layers[0].output) But I get this value error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
coro = func()
File "\<input\>", line 1, in \<module\>
File "/Users/marinopavone/PycharmProjects/RBF_layer_PORCO_DIO/modules_files/Classifiier_function.py", line 186, in get_encoder_model
encoded_model = Model(inputs=NN_model.input, outputs=NN_model.layers\[0\].output)
File "/Users/marinopavone/PycharmProjects/Degradation_Simulator/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 228, in input
return self.\_get_node_attribute_at_index(0, "input_tensors", "input")
File "/Users/marinopavone/PycharmProjects/Degradation_Simulator/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 259, in \_get_node_attribute_at_index
raise ValueError(
ValueError: The layer sequential has never been called and thus has no defined input.

I kindly ask you if Anyone can see the problem ?
best
PS I would like to remark that the code was actually working, so it shoul be some compatibility problem that now is
Here the current settings: I am using PyCharm 2023.3.4 (Professional Edition) with Tensorflow 2.16.1 on a macosx sonoma 14.3 with M3 chip.
I tried to unistal and reinstall bot tensor flow and keras (stand alone) and I tried to use different path of the function Model:

    from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, Model
    from tensorflow.keras,model import Sequential, Model
    from keras import Sequential, Model

and i often rebooted both pycharm and the computer itself, but error persist

I had a similar error in a code that worked in 2023 and does not work anymore in 2024. The problem was solved by replacing :
encoded_model = Model(inputs=NN_model.input,outputs=NN_model.layers[0].output)

by
encoded_model = Model(inputs=NN_model.layers[0].input,outputs=NN_model.layers[0].output)

or by
encoded_model = Model(inputs=NN_model.inputs,outputs=NN_model.layers[0].output)

I hope this helps solving your problem.
